# When application creates a lot of WCF connector classes, all connections to the server time out

Tags: c#, wcf, net.tcp

I've got a WCF net.tcp server, which exposes a service with 2 methods:

```
string Get(location);
void Put(location);
```

`maxConnections` is set to `int.MaxValue`. on client side, `maxConnections` is set to 800. No exceptions on the server are raised

and I've got a client application, which sometimes creates 100+ threads, each of which may connect to the server at any moment in time.

When the threads share the connector class, the app works fine. When I let each thread create it's own connector, when I use 20-30 threads, each thread works fine. But when the app creates 50+ threads, all connections suddenly start timing out.

```
System.TimeoutException: The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The socket transfer timed out after 00:01:00. You have exceeded the timeou
t set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
 host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MySource.Get(String account)
   at MyService.Get(String account) in d:\Users\menkaur\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\Service References\MySourceService\Reference.cs:line 99
   at auto_liker_bot.Program.<>c__DisplayClass58.<>c__DisplayClass60.<Main>b__4c(IMySource _mySource) in d:\Users\menkaur\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\my-project\Program.cs:line 473
   at auto_liker_bot.Program.PerformAction(UInt64 threadId, IMySource& mySource, Action`1 action) in d:\Users\menkaur\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\my-project\Program.cs:line 919
```

This is not the first time I've noticed something like that happening to WCF classes.

Is this a hard limitation for WCF, or is there a setting that I can change to get rid of this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

What you are experiencing is the limit on the number of connections to a host from a client. It is not set by WCF but WCF is not immune to it. You will need to increase it. Check out:

- [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library) if you want to set it in the code
- [ConnectionManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx) element in config file

Basically you only have 2 connections to the same host by default. As the number of threads go up, the connection requests increase and get queued but since there is only 2 available, at some point you start to get timeouts.

Comment: set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit=800`; the problem still remains